# Improving performance on multiple regular expression matching

Tags: c#, regex, console, .net-4.5

I apologize if a similar question has been asked, my google queries after 2 days yielded no results. It could be the search strings I have been using.

Anyway, I am attempting to improve performance on an application I am writing. It currently opens a text file, reads the entire contents, and matches Regex Patterns. The files are typically no larger than 10MB, however each file can contain up to ~70k lines (or more, the file size is set to grow no larger than 10MB though)

Here is the relevant code block:

```
    Regex m1 = new Regex(pattern_1);
    Regex m2 = new Regex(pattern_2);
    Regex m3 = new Regex(pattern_3);
    Regex m4 = new Regex(pattern_4);
    Regex m5 = new Regex(pattern_5); 
    Regex m6 = new Regex(pattern_6); 
    Regex m7 = new Regex(pattern_7); 

        foreach (string file in files)
            using (StreamReader fr = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                string lr;

                while ((lr = fr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Match m1_1 = m1.Match(lr);
                    Match m2_2 = storageSize.Match(lr);
                    Match m3_3 = logStart.Match(lr);
                    Match m4_4 = mergeStart.Match(lr);
                    Match m5_5 = filePatcher.Match(lr);
                    Match m6_6 = mergeEnd.Match(lr);
                    Match m7_7 = logEnd.Match(lr);

                    if (m1_1.Success)
                    {
                        string m1_str = m1_1.Value;
                    //do stuff
                    }
                    if (m2_2.Success)
                    {
                        string m2_str = m2_2.Value;
                    //do stuff
                    }

                }
            }
```

I took the rest of the success statements out, but you get the idea.

Each one of the 7 regex patterns can only match a single line (there are absolutely zero overlaps where 2 regex queries can hit the same line)

For the sake of performance, I thought it would be a good idea to do the following (in what i call 'programmatic english'):

If match.success = true, move to next lr (line read), and start at m1. This would (in theory) save some time trying to match the rest of the regex patterns.

How would I go about doing this, or is there a better attack angle for improving performance? I'm currently testing with RegexOptions.Compiled as well, since these strings can be extremely long/complex. I'm also performing the same action on files contained within a ZIP, and reading/matching from memory.

I'm fairly new to C# (some, barely any honestly, experience with c++ from about 12 years ago), and I've got my application doing what I want it to; I just can't figure out the performance aspect to help speed it along :)

Edit: For those asking for the Regex definitions I have, I can't post them for privacy reasons. The best I can do is this extremely simplified sample:

```
Line 1 - [Sentence] This is a sample of User1's Sentence, the total length is 564 characters.
Line 2 - [Sentence] I'm writing another sentence just because.
Line 3 - Garbage Sentence
Sentence Line 4
Line 5 - [Sentence] This is a sample of User1's Sentence, the total length is 10459275 characters.
```

My pattern to get line 1 and 5 would be:

```
Regex m1 = new Regex (@"\[.*\bSentence\].*User1.*\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Edit2: Ended up fixing my performance problem. I spent some time with beer, then took a step back and re-evaluated what I was doing. Turn's out that the RegEx patterns I was looking for were already unique enough that I could just do if line.contains("words"), then do a regex match on the one i couldn't get unique enough to filter that one down.

went from 2 hours, to ~6 seconds (on a MUCH larger file package).

Comment: Do these pattern show up in a regular order e.g. in a block?

Comment: What patterns are you matching? And what are your current patterns?

Comment: Can you show the patterns you are using, and some sample input

Comment: I honestly can't show the patterns I'm using, due to privacy. They don't appear in a block anywhere; the matches could be anywhere in the text document.

Comment: Since you cannot show the patterns... I will speculate. If they are 100% non-overlapping, you could use a single regex that is m1|m2|m3|m4|m5 or ^m1|m2|m3|m4|m5$ depending on your case. I would also name the groups. That way you do not need to use 7 regexes. Also knowing what it is exactly you are trying to achieve could lead to more performance gains by giving the regex engine the opportunity to do more work (i.e. match lines against larger blocks of text, not line by line). If I were you, I'd go back to the drawing board and figure out what it is exactly that I want to achieve in the end.

Comment: To clarify, the biggest performance gain you can have in your case is a paradigm shift, in HOW you obtain the results, All the recommendations talk about parallelism, I would say that depends on WHAT you want to do with the results. If this is a simple "filter by type of line, don't care about the final order of things" you are definitely doing more work than you should with this code. Also, please provide more details into the performance you are getting. Since you want to improve it, I suspect it is bad, but how bad? Are you sure regex is the bottleneck? :)

Comment: I believe the problem may be 2-fold. 1 is checking for the match. I was being a bit silly and only testing loose files initially. 2 is honestly streaming from ZIP. As an example, I created a ZIP file with 7 10MB files (identical to files I'm actually going to use this against, but nowhere near a true amount), and it took 2H10M to process the ZIP contents, while it took 9M to process the unzipped files. So I spent a couple hours revisiting that code as well.

Comment: And you are correct; 100% non-overlapping. However, I do need the results to be chronologically in order based on a time stamp at the beginning of every line in my final result, to do other stuff with later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the C# part, but for optimizing Regex efficiency (which from what you describe is a bottle neck for the performance of your program) I find using a debugger on the pattern is helpful:

You can try https://www.debuggex.com in PCRE mode. and for what to try to change in your regex (which is not in the question) start to read up on the gory details regex: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-optimizations.html#optimization

Hope this helps

Comment: It does, to some extent :) especially the optimization page. There's a few minor things I can change to my RegEx (i think) to have them match quicker, but I think my bottleneck will still end up being performing 7 matches on a line where only 0 or 1 can match before moving to the next line, across ~70k lines in x files.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're reusing the Regexes in a loop, you're on the right track with the RegexOptions.Compiled option.  If you have many Regexes to reuse and the patterns are static, you may want to explore the Regex.CompileToAssembly method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ek5zak6(v=vs.110).aspx

As for your request to "If match.success = true, move to next lr (line read), and start at m1. This would (in theory) save some time trying to match the rest of the regex patterns."  This can be accomplished with the `IsMatch` method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4(v=vs.110).aspx) and the `continue` keyword inside the while loop.

```
while ((lr = fr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     if (m1.IsMatch(lr))
     {
         string m1_str = m1.Match(lr).Value;
         //do stuff
         continue;
     }

     if (m2.IsMatch(lr))
     {
        //same idea
     }

     //and so on...
}
```

As an afterthought, you would want to order your matching attempts in order of most likely to match to least likely to match, using any problem specific knowledge you may have.

Comment: Interesting. I can recompile this twice, once using async (if I can wrap my head around it), and once using this method, to compare both results against my original write up.

There may be some variables I have to change, but thats not on the topic of performance.

Comment: Well the good news is you could do both!  The async approach above aims to improve performance by processing multiple files at once, while my approach simply moves on to the next line as soon as a match is found and the 'stuff' is done.

Comment: ooOOoo, fancy :)

Comment: this is still hilariously bad. i still need to implement the async (that may be the key here, i hope), but im currently sitting at ~45 min runtime for 3 10MB files. Granted, I'm streaming these directly to memory from a compressed archive (im avoiding extracting, reading, deleting; because i dont want this app to delete anything whatsoever, liability if it SOMEHOW screws up). but yeah, this is painfully slow for what it should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your options

1. Refine/optimize your patterns
2. Parallel Work loads
3. Write the parser yourself

The easiest approach (with the existing code) is a mix of `1 and 2`. Yet the truth is you could probably get much better (factors better) performance out of `2 and 3`.

In regards to `2 and 3` you could load each file into memory, use `unsafe` , `fixed` and `pointer` access and efficiently check for the footprint of each pattern with a **O(n)** *Time Complexity* and better with a parallel approach. I.e one check per character in multiple threads simultaneously.

My guess is your current approach (at best) searches each line for every pattern, however at worst each pattern is searching each line many times.

**Example**

```
fixed (char* p = expression)
{
   var max = p + expression.Length;
   for (var i = p; i < max; i++)
   {
      if (*i = 's') // just an example
      {
          // Potential pattern
          ...
```

Obviously this will take more time code, however if time is your concern it will far out weigh any regex solution as is currently shown (IMO)

Comment: On your last line, correct. It's looping through 7 times searching for a pattern, and if one of them matches, returns the entire line. The continue method get's me through them quicker, but its still line by line, file by file, singularly.

Comment: @noodlesdefyyou If you past your 7 `regex patterns` in your question it might help people understand what optimizations could be done

Comment: I wish I could. The best I can say is I'm searching for a complex sentence that has multiple variables in the sentence, but identifiable by unique patterns in the sentence.

IE:

Line 1 - [Sentence] This is a sample of User1's Sentence, the total length is 564 characters.
Line 2 - [Sentence] I'm writing another sentence just because.

My pattern to get line 1 would be:

Regex m1 = new Regex (@"\[.*\bSentence\].*User1.*\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, you can try to get a better performance using `Async Tasks`

```
public static async Task ForEachAsync<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, Task> func)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        await func(file);
    }
}
```

Now, you can do something like

```
await files.ToList().ForEachAsync(async i => {
    await ReadStream(i);
});

void ReadStream(File file){
    using (StreamReader fr = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        string lr;

        while ((lr = fr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Match m1_1 = m1.Match(lr);
            Match m2_2 = storageSize.Match(lr);
            Match m3_3 = logStart.Match(lr);
            Match m4_4 = mergeStart.Match(lr);
            Match m5_5 = filePatcher.Match(lr);
            Match m6_6 = mergeEnd.Match(lr);
            Match m7_7 = logEnd.Match(lr);

            if (m1_1.Success)
            {
                string m1_str = m1_1.Value;
                //do stuff
            }
            if (m2_2.Success)
            {
                 string m2_str = m2_2.Value;
                 //do stuff
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Funny you mention async :) I looked in to async/await earlier this week, and couldn't quite wrap my head around it. I'll give async another whirl